# How to make Ubuntu 22.04 work with a Radeon RX 7900 XTX?

Tags: kernel, amd-graphics, radeon, initramfs, mesa

I know that for such new hardware would be better to use a rolling release distro or at least the latest 22.10, but I was wondering if with some tinkering it is still possible to get the latest LTS to work.

As far as I know, to get a 7900 XTX to work on linux you need at least these:

1. Kernel 6.x+
2. LLVM 15+
3. Mesa 22.3+
4. latest linux-firmware for `/lib/firmware/amdgpu/` (and rebuild `initramfs`)

Is it possible and, if yes, what would be the best way to achieve this on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get an AMD Radeon RX 7900 XT(X) to work with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, you can follow these steps:

1. Install the latest OEM kernel available by running the command:

   ```
   sudo apt install linux-oem-22.04c
   ```
2. Download and install the latest kernel firmware from [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git) by running these commands:

   ```
   wget https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/snapshot/linux-firmware-20230919.tar.gz
   tar -xf linux-firmware-20230919.tar.gz
   sudo cp linux-firmware-20230919/amdgpu/* /lib/firmware/amdgpu/
   sudo update-initramfs -uk 'all'
   ```
3. Install the [kisak-mesa PPT](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekisak/+archive/ubuntu/kisak-mesa) by running these commands
   (this PPA will take care of providing the latest stable mesa and llvm15):

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
   sudo apt upgrade
   ```
4. Ensure there is no modprobe blacklist for amdgpu by running the command:

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf
   ```

If you use Xorg instead of Wayland and have the issue where the mouse cursor is invisible, you can try to create the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-modesetting.conf` with the following content:

```
Section "Device"
      Identifier "modesetting"
      Driver "modesetting"
EndSection
```

This should make the latest LTS work with your hardware.

Comment: For every apt install/upgrade operation, dkms tries to rebuild the driver wrapper and fails.  This leaves me with a /etc/modeprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf after every apt operation pretty much.

Comment: I'm not experiencing this issue (just tested to ran `apt update && apt upgrade`). Do you have any other PPAs or dynamic kernel modules that may cause this?

Comment: If you use the amdgpu primary drivers I believe they have a dkms component to it.  'amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics,....'   The performance improvement is quite substantial.

Comment: What do you mean by "amdgpu primary drivers"? Do you mean the `amdgpu-pro`, the one that you download from the AMD website? Or are you talking about the open source `amdgpu` from Mesa? I'm using the latter and I never heard about this extra step. Can you please link some documentation about it?

Comment: Performance goes up from 6kfps to 13kfps using the AMDGPU stack with glmark2. https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/latest/  https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers

Comment: Can you please try to do some benchmarks with GravityMark? This way we can compare easily the performances: https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/10ldyhn/gravitymark_benchmark_a_gpu/

Comment: Mesa and kernel upgrade was sufficient for me to make 7900XT works.

Answer (score 1):

As @MadMan2064 mentioned in the comments, `amdgpu-install` from https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers worked for me with a Radeon RX 7900 XT. Even though I'm on Ubuntu 22.10 (kinetic), the 22.04 version worked. I installed the `.deb` file and ran `amdgpu-install` without any arguments, and that was sufficient. No need to install a special kernel or add a ppa.

Answer (score 0):

I also had trouble installing Ubuntu 22.04 correctly (I had a black screen with a flashing underscore), but I was able to launch it in recovery mode, where I had access to the terminal. What worked for me was installing Ubuntu 20.04 first and then upgrading to 22.04.

My GPU is an RX 7900XT.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! This worked for me. I have a Radeon RX 580 on Ubuntu 22.04. I installed the OEM kernel (from recovery mode) but not the latest firmware or the kisak-mesa PPT. Additionally I uninstalled the (horrible) amdgpu-dkms package which caused my white screen to begin with, though I thought I had already done that. I also commented out the amdgpu blacklist, rather than removing the file. I think that is what fixed the problem.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1319285)