# How to make my computer recognize dedicated GPU instead of using integrated one?

Tags: crash, gpu, gpu-driver, amdgpu

I have Ryzen 7950x and 7900 xtx.
My computer uses GPU integrated on 7950x.
I found this out trying to use Pytorch, and it showed that I have no dedicated GPU.

I would like to be able to use 7900 xtx with Pytorch.

I don't know if this will help, but I have installed drivers to be able to use computer like shown here:
[How to make Ubuntu 22.04 work with a Radeon RX 7900 XTX?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1451506/how-to-make-ubuntu-22-04-work-with-a-radeon-rx-7900-xtx).

I have also tried installing dedicated drivers:
https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-rx-7000-series/amd-radeon-rx-7900-series/amd-radeon-rx-7900xtx

However, it crashes every time I try installing it. It says that it failed to build dkms. Than it crashes after restarting.

I have written more details in my previous question, I can put them here if needed.

I have Ubuntu 22.04.2, because it is shown that drivers are available for it.

Can someone help me?
Sorry, if I show some angry tone, but I just want to use my new computer and do some deep learning.
As I have seen it's always the problem with AMD drivers, my mistake for not knowing that before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how applicable this is for you, but when I started using linux I was using an old r9270x, I had to enable "pitcairn support" in GRUB before I could use the card properly. Perhaps checking out any documentation on that might be helpful. Sorry I don't know much more.

you can find get to the grub file using sudo nano /boot/grub/grub.conf to make any edits you need. Once you are done run sudo update-grub and then reboot the computer.

Please check other sources asides from this though, I am still relatively new to linux/ubuntu and I'm a little paranoid about making changes, I don't want to be liable for bricking your install.